# html post to php to generate XML file?

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm having hard time to do a php post to a XML data here is my form:

```
<form action="../xml/data.php" method"post">
  <p>Name</p>
  <input name='name' required><br>
  <p>ID</p>
  <input name"id" required>
  <input type='submit' value ="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$s_id=$_POST['id'];
$s_name=$_POST['name'];
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$student = $xml -> createElement("student");
$xml -> appendChild($student);

$id_value = $xml ->createTextNode("$s_id");
$id -> appendChild($id_value);
$name = $xml -> createElement("name");
$student -> appendChild($name);
$name_value=$xml->createTextNode("$s_name");
$name->appendChild($name_value);
$xml ->formatOutput = true;

$xml -> save("mydata.xml");
?>
```

But it doesn't make the mydata.xml file and not working :s not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: At what point does it break? Does it get to the end but you can find a file, or is it somewhere else that it errors? Do you see an error that gives you a line to look at? These are all important questions that should be answered.

Comment: i get error after submitting the form: Notice: Undefined index: id in on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: name in \xml\data.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: id in data.php on line 9I get error after submitting the form as:

Comment: Why should we think `$id` has `DOMDocument` properties? Where do you want to append the text stored in `$id_value`?

Comment: yes.If i change id field think might work? i give it ago now,

Comment: `appendChild()` is used on `DOMNode`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `=` in your form tag:

```
<form action="../xml/data.php" method"post">
```

should be

```
<form action="../xml/data.php" method="post">
```

And also here

```
<input name"id" required>
```

should be

```
<input name="id" required>
```

@PHPglue is correct too - `$id -> appendChild($id_value);` should presumably be `$student -> appendChild($id_value);`.

Comment: still getting error after submitting the form, undefined index errors

Comment: That's the last line of my answer - change `$id -> appendChild($id_value);` to `$student -> appendChild($id_value);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few equals signs in your form code:

```
<form action="../xml/data.php" method"post">
```

and

```
<input name"id" required>
```

should be:

```
<form action="../xml/data.php" method="post">
```

and

```
<input name="id" required>
```

Comment: still getting Undefined index: id line 2 and line 5